# How to set DNS return ipv6

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6

I wanna get ipv6 when ping hostname, but with AD DNS manager, it always give ipv4. and below is my info. currently for it to work with ipv6 is either add ipv6 to hosts file or delete the ipv4 from DNS manager. except this 2, it there other solution?

**DC1**
ipv4: 192.168.5.5 (dns: 192.168.5.6, 127.0.0.1)
ipv6: fd00::abcd:fa05/96 (dns: fd00::abcd:fa06, ::1)

**DC2**
ipv4: 192.168.5.6 (dns: 192.168.5.5, 127.0.0.1)
ipv6: fd00::abcd:fa06/96 (dns: fd00::abcd:fa05, ::1)

**Server1**
ipv4: 192.168.5.7 (dns: 192.168.5.5, 192.168.5.6)
ipv6: fd00::abcd:fa07/96 (dns: fd00::abcd:fa05, fd00::abcd:fa06)

**Server2**
ipv4: 192.168.5.8 (dns: 192.168.5.5, 192.168.5.6)
ipv6: fd00::abcd:fa08/96 (dns: fd00::abcd:fa05, fd00::abcd:fa06)

Currently i can ping each ip from each other.
eg. 192.168.5.7 to 192.168.5.5, 192.168.5.6 to 192.168.5.8, even ipv6 fd00::abcd:fa08 to fd00::abcd:fa07, fd00::abcd:fa07 to fd00::abcd:fa05.....

but when i ping hostname eg. ping server2, ping dc1 or dc2.domain.local. **how to make this resolve in ipv6**, by right this is default, but now most of time dns return ipv4.
i try

> 1. set ipv6 in hosts file. it worked.
> 2. remove ipv4 in DNS manager in DC. it work from short time, after that the ipv4 will auto update back to DC.
> 3. dont set dns for server1, server2. then possible it resolve in ipv6. can ping server1/server2 from server2/server1.
> 4. i set DisabledComponents to 0x00, but seem same. nth change (after restart).
>    so is there any way to set DNS return in ipv6 but also keep the ipv4 in dns manager.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the DNS will generally respond with what it's asked for, so I'd guess that your ping app is defaulting to IPv4. If you tell ping to try for an IPv6 host, it should get the IPv6 address. `ping -6 server1` should do what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks @tsc_chazz, if like that means dns server no issue.  ping -4 will get ipv4. ping -6 will get ipv6. but how i make sure ping default with hostname will get ipv6? i already set DisabledComponents to prefer ipv6 (to all server), but some server it can get ipv6. not sure why.  where can i check for it? cause now mostly ping default will get ipv4.

Comment: Whether you get an ipv4 or an ipv6 DNS response will depend on the program making the request. BSD ping does not seem to have any option to choose the default; whatever its default is, I'd guess it looks at that first and then falls back to the other if the first doesn't work. Windows ping from server 2016 / Windows 10 and later seems to default to ipv6. All you can really do to force IPv6 is make sure your server asks for it first.

Comment: Thanks @tsc_chazz, ya. this is i means also. i want to make sure force ipv6. but like u say latest windows default will do this. and the most influnce key is DisabledComponents. 
and the dns setting. i want to keep ipv4/6. just if ipv6 fail then it will use ipv4. but when i ping both ipv4/ipv6 is success.  means ping ipv6 no issue, but why default it will get ipv4 when default should get ipv6. this is the part i want to check. not really sure will router/firewall influence it as well.  and thank again.

Comment: Of course router and firewall will influence it, as will the network you're connected to outside it - some ISPs still have not upgraded their routers to handle IPv6 and any attempt to retrieve an IPv6 address across those networks will fail. But the basic fact remains that the thing that determines whether you connect IPv4 or IPv6 is the client asking to make the connection; there is nothing you can realistically do at the DNS end to enforce it except not have any IPv4 addresses defined, and you already have tried that.

Comment: finally got the solution i want. yes, but router/firewall seem not influnce in my case. it just internal only. and my solution is related prefixpolicies. early i set to lower. i thought it will take the lower like metric. but this take the higher value.  Thank you

Comment: Yeah it's the requesting side that controls it. For instance at work the network (rather than the app or client machine) is set to prefer ipv6, so if I ping something that has both v4 and v6 records I'll always get a v6 response unless I specifically request the v4.